# Using $this->element inside a customHelper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, helper

I am building a custom helper for my app.
On one of the methods I am trying to insert an element.
For this I am using:

```
$El = ClassRegistry::getObject('view'); 
$El->element('my_element', array('plugin'=>'my_plugin'));
```

after debuging $El i get the response false.

Do you guys / girls know if this operation is even possible inside a Helper?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2.0 the view object isn't added to class registry. In your helper `$this->_View` has the reference to view object. Including elements inside helpers isn't advisable.

Comment: I need to return some HTML this is why I choose to use this element. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: Use the Html, Form etc. helpers as needed in your custom helper.

Comment: What if you have a big piece of HTML to render at once and a lot of data for it? Should I write a lot of code with HTMLHelper?

Comment: Depends what you want to do. You could echo HTML directly from the Helper function (bleh). Looks likely that you should consider using the element in favour of a helper. e.g.: instead of `$this->CustomHelper->function($var)` just call the element `echo $this->element('element', ['var' => $var]);` and it could do PHP and/or call other Helpers if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the view object as parameter function helper. For instance:

```
class ComponentHelper extends AppHelper {
    public function checkboxes( $form, .... ) {
        ...
        $form->element( '...' );
        ...
    }
}
```

In the form:

```
$this->Component->checkboxes( $this, .... );
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2 you'll need to call the `_View` object if trying to access elements within a helper - e.g.:

```
$this->_View->Element($element, $options);
```

This is not really preferable and it sounds like you should consider using an element directly in favour of a Helper.

e.g.: instead of `$this->CustomHelper->method($var)` just call the element from the view as per normal `echo $this->element('element', ['var' => $var]);` and it could do PHP/logic and/or call other Helpers if required.